# Light bulb socket cover

Tags: electrical, safety, bulb, cover, socket

Where can I get a light bulb socket cover for my never used outside flood light sockets?  I don't use the light fixture, the flood lamps are too heavy to keep in the sockets as the fixture comes detached from the house.  I'm looking for a simple solution.  I have inside flood lamps but they don't fit properly in the sockets.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a photo or two of the light?

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a "plug" that completely covers the socket, but you can get a two-prong adapter like this that will fill in the Edison socket and only leave the two prongs opened.

[image]

Comment: That would have been my suggestion. You can then stick a childproofing cap in it if the slots bother you.

Comment: @keshlam Good call - I have kids so I should have thought about that combo.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the flood light sockets with nothing in them is about as safe as leaving an electric socket without a plug in it*. How many of those do you have around your house?

*Unless I've missed something and an outside flood light is massively different to any other light fitting. I'm assuming it's [something like this](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-42W-Professional-PIR-Twinspot-Grey/p/162470).

Comment: I disagree that this situation is comparable to an electric outlet in a house for two reasons: 1) outside, rain and debris can get blown into the light socket. Not an issue inside. 2) the openings on an outlet are much, much smaller.

Comment: @HenryJackson - If it's designed as an outside lamp, then it should be waterproof! On my own one the bulb is contained under a waterproof lid. To replace the bulb you take the lid off, change the bulb, put the lid back on. If you did the same, without actually putting a new bulb in, it'd still be waterproof. With respect to the openings - well it all depends on the bulb! Screw bulb, bayonet bulb, GU10 bulb, G9...

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall a product on the open market made specifically to cover flood light fixtures. If you are concerned about keeping the elements and debris out of the socket orient the fixture to 90 degree's.